# Hibernate and instead of insert trigger - how to handle primary keys generation?

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, sql-insert

I have a hibernate entity mapped to Oracle view with instead of insert, update and delete trigger, which call stored procedures for creation, insertion and deletion of the entity. Entity primary key is generated in stored procedure. When i insert only one row in transaction, all is OK, but when i try to insert two or more entities, i have NonUniqueObjectException. On Oracle side i can modify only trigger, not view or procedures.
There are current class mapping and trigger:

```
<class dynamic-insert='true' dynamic-update='true' entity-name='...' table='...'>
    <composite-id>
        <key-property name='FaultId' type='long' column='FAULT_ID'/>
        <key-property name='RowVersion' type='long' column='ROWVERSION'/>
    </composite-id>
    ...
    other properties...
    ...
</class>

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trigger_name INSTEAD OF
DELETE OR
INSERT OR
UPDATE ON ... REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD FOR EACH ROW DECLARE NEW_ID NUMBER;
BEGIN
    IF INSERTING THEN
        insert_proc_call(NEW_ID, ...); -- NEW_ID is out parameter.
    END IF;
    IF UPDATING THEN
        update_proc_call(:NEW.FAULT_ID, :NEW.ROWVERSION, ...);
    END IF;
    IF DELETING THEN
        delete_proc_call(:OLD.FAULT_ID, :OLD.ROWVERSION);
    END IF;
END trigger_name;
```

How i can handle this situation in Hibernate?

Comment: If the entity is mapped to a view, how do you expect to insert, update or delete it?

Comment: Through the trigger on this view.